# Rails won't serve static files in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production

I recently updated my app from 2.3.8 to 3.0.rc, but after a while in development environment I tried the production environment. But now it won't serve static files.

I use standard development and production environment settings, and have no unique gems for either environments. Everything works like a charm in development, but it won't serve static files in production.

Using ruby-1.8.7-p299 and every gem is up to date. Using WEBrick on my server, running `rails s -e production -p 3001`

Anyone with some solutions or tips to this ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After some extra digging I found a setting in the production.rb file, `config.serve_static_assets` which was set to false, and since I'm not running apache or nginx the static files where not served. *blush*

Comment: Nice. Hopefully you've just saved many persons from such future blushes :).

Answer (score 9):

For rails 5 you should set environment variable RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES

Comment: This came in handy when debugging a `webpacker` problem: `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=1 bin/rails s`